# MySQL subquery error on multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables posts, terms and relationships.

posts table:

```
ID     title      
1      abc
2      cdf
```

terms table:

```
term_id  slug
1        jeans
2        shirts
```

relationships table:

```
object_id    taxonomy_id
1             1
2             1
```

The MySQL query I used to try to list the titles which have "jeans" related to them

```
SELECT posts.title 
FROM posts, terms, relationships
WHERE (SELECT terms.term_id FROM terms WHERE terms.slug LIKE '%jeans%')
AND (SELECT relationships.object_id FROM relationships WHERE terms.term_id = relationships.taxonomy_id)
AND (posts.ID = relationships.object_id)
```

It gives me error #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row. How can I fix this?

Comment: Your SQL statement is wrong. You need column names right after WHERE and ANDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT posts.title
FROM posts INNER JOIN relationships ON (posts.ID = relationships.object_id)
           INNER JOIN terms ON (terms.term_id = relationships.taxonomy_id)
WHERE terms.slug LIKE '%jeans%';
```

I don't have your tables, so I can't test, but I think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT p.title 
  FROM posts p
  JOIN relationships r
    ON r.object_id = p.ID
  JOIN terms t
    ON t.term_id = r.taxonomy_id 
 WHERE t.slug LIKE '%jeans%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT posts.title
FROM posts 
    INNER JOIN relationships ON (posts.ID = relationships.object_id)
    INNER JOIN terms ON (terms.term_id = relationships.taxonomy_id)
WHERE 
    (terms.slug LIKE '%jeans%')
AND 
    (terms.term_id = relationships.taxonomy_id)
AND 
    (posts.ID = relationships.object_id)
```